# How to override console.log, console.warn, console.error in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, console

I'm very close to getting it working how I want.

See the code below and its output.

```
import util from 'util';

import chalk from 'chalk'; // https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk

import { getFormattedUtcDatetimeNow } from './datetime.js';

const success = chalk.bgGreen;

const styles = {
  log: chalk,
  error: chalk.bold.red,
  warn: chalk.hex('#FFA500'), // Orange color
  info: chalk.gray,
  debug: chalk.blue,
};

type Arguments = any;

// TODO: Fix this since it leads to weird displays of square brackets [].
function getArgumentsPreserved(providedArguments: Arguments): string {
  // https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/
  // https://github.com/chalk/chalk/issues/118#issuecomment-1221385194
  return util.inspect(providedArguments, { colors: false, depth: null });
}

for (const style of Object.keys(styles)) {
  const originalStyle = console[style];
  const callback = styles[style];
  console[style] = function (...providedArguments: Arguments) {
    Reflect.apply(originalStyle, this, [getFormattedUtcDatetimeNow(), callback(getArgumentsPreserved(providedArguments))]);
  };
}
```

Output after running commands:

```
const object = { ab: 'cd', one: { two: 3 } };
console.log('demo', object);
2022-10-22 12:45:08 UTC [ 'demo', { ab: 'cd', one: { two: 3 } } ]
```

How can I avoid those extra `[` and `]` added by `util.inspect()`?

Also, how can I add appropriate types to avoid these TypeScript errors?

```
    shared/helpers/logging.ts:29:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'originalLog'.

    29 type originalType = typeof originalLog;
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
    shared/helpers/logging.ts:32:39 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Console'.
      No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Console'.

    32   const originalStyle: originalType = console[style];
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    shared/helpers/logging.ts:33:20 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ log: Chalk & ChalkFunction & { supportsColor: false | ColorSupport; Level: Level; Color: Color; ForegroundColor: ForegroundColor; BackgroundColor: BackgroundColor; Modifiers: Modifiers; stderr: Chalk & { ...; }; }; error: Chalk; warn: Chalk; info: Chalk; debug: Chalk; }'.
      No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ log: Chalk & ChalkFunction & { supportsColor: false | ColorSupport; Level: Level; Color: Color; ForegroundColor: ForegroundColor; BackgroundColor: BackgroundColor; Modifiers: Modifiers; stderr: Chalk & { ...; }; }; error: Chalk; warn: Chalk; info: Chalk; debug: Chalk; }'.

    33   const callback = styles[style];
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    shared/helpers/logging.ts:34:3 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Console'.
      No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Console'.

    34   console[style] = function (...providedArguments: Arguments) {
```

[image]

### Update after comments below

```
for (const style of Object.keys(styles) as Array<keyof Console>) {
  const originalStyle = console[style];
  const callback = styles[style];
  console[style] = function (...providedArguments: Arguments) {
    Reflect.apply(originalStyle, this, [getFormattedUtcDatetimeNow(), callback(getArgumentsPreserved(providedArguments))]);
  };
}
```

[image: ts error]

[image: ts errors]

### Update #2

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your function should map over each element and join the results instead. You get the extra `[` and `]` because you are inspecting an array, the arguments.

```
type Arguments = any[]; // needs to be an array to use `map`

function getArgumentsPreserved(providedArguments: Arguments): string {
  return providedArguments.map((a) => util.inspect(a, { colors: false, depth: null })).join(" ");
}
```

In your loop, you can cast `Object.keys(styles)` to keys of `styles`:

```
for (const style of Object.keys(styles) as Array<keyof typeof styles>) {
  const originalStyle = console[style];
  const callback = styles[style];
  console[style] = function (...providedArguments: Arguments) {
    Reflect.apply(originalStyle, this, [getFormattedUtcDatetimeNow(), callback(getArgumentsPreserved(providedArguments))]);
  } as any;
}
```

then you shouldn't get errors when trying to index into `console` with the key `style`.
Now unfortunately I do think the easiest way to fix the error when reassigning the method is to cast to `any`. Here it does no harm (and doesn't spread), so it's fine to use `any`.

Comment: `getArgumentsPreserved` looks great! Thanks so much! For the loop, now the only TS error is: `Type '(...providedArguments: any) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (condition?: boolean | undefined, ...data: any[]): void; (value: any, message?: string | undefined, ...optionalParams: any[]): void; } & { (): void; (): void; } & { (label?: string | undefined): void; (label?: string | undefined): void; } & ... 19 more ... & ((label?: string | undefined) => void)'.`

Comment: ... `Type '(...providedArguments: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'ConsoleConstructor'.
    Type '(...providedArguments: any) => void' provides no match for the signature 'new (stdout: WritableStream, stderr?: WritableStream | undefined, ignoreErrors?: boolean | undefined): Console'.ts(2322)`

Comment: @Ryan Oh well that's because you're "changing" the type of the console method. It has many overloads but you just have one signature. I'd just cast to `any` here... It's simple and doesn't have adverse effects.

Comment: Thank you! I was wrong. There are actually still multiple TS errors. I updated the question above with a new section at the bottom. I'm not quite following what you mean for me to do next. Thanks so much for your help! I have a feeling I'll be using this code in every TS project going forward. It seems like it will be useful.